# Power Automate Create File From Base64 String Not Working

Tags: create-document

I've searched for this issue and saw people with similar problems but nothing has been able to resolve my issue. I'm converting a file to base64, doing an http post and then trying to convert it back into a file in sharepoint.

The base64 string is valid and ive tried using it in other environments.

The string is passed and stored correctly within power automate.

However as soon as I use create file the resulting file is corrupt.

I've tried base64tobinary, parsing to a variable, compose, etc. Nothing works.

If I copy the variable value and use try another method like python to turn it into a file, it works. But as soon as i use that same variable with create file the result does not open.

I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-convert-base64-file-into-docx-pdf-file/td-p/912759 . You need to wrap it in an object specifying the content type of the file

Comment: That was it, thanks!